# Detect CPU Speed/Memory/Internet Speed using Java?

Tags: java, memory, networking, cpu, ram

Is it possible within Java to identify the total CPU speed available as well as the total system memory? Network connection speed to the web would also be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really depends on your OS, since Java will tell you *little* about the underlying machine. Unfortunately you have to use differing approaches depending on your OS.

If you're on Linux, take a look at the `/proc/cpuinfo` filesystem for CPU info. `/proc` generally has a wealth of information. Network (IO) will be reflected via the command `ifconfig`.

If you're on Windows, a useful tool is [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx), which provides access to all sorts of low-level hardware stats. You can run WMI scripts via [CScript](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cscript_overview.mspx?mfr=true). [Here's a page of examples](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/wmi/samples/hw/) of WMI scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [SIGAR](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) can provide some of the things you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
Properties p = System.getProperties();   
    p.list(System.out); 
    System.out.print("Total CPU:");
    System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    System.out.println("Max Memory:" + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() + "\n" + "available Memory:" + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    System.out.println("os.name=" + System.getProperty("os.name"));
```

try above

Comment: `java testtest.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Properties
 Properties p = System.getProperties();   `

Comment: @Tim you should import the Properties first i.e. `import java.util.*`

Answer (score 0):

Memory stats are available from the [Runtime](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) object.  And take a look a jconsole, a graphical client that presents information about a JMX-enabled Java Virtual Machine.  It shows a lot of information including CPU usage, so you could write your own client that accesses the JMX information too.

Comment: Yeah it seems like Java is very protective over how applications can interact with hardware. The memory stats I saw from the Runtime object are just what the VM will take, not the actual total amount available