# Monitor Network speed in Java on Windows

Tags: java, windows

Is there an API that can monitor network activity -- data transfer speeds(downstream)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly dependent on platform.  You can use native commands to get this info

- [This might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297870/detect-cpu-speed-memory-internet-speed-using-java)