# How to access bios information with java?

Tags: java, windows-7, bios

Is it possible to get the bios information of windows 7 using java, the minimum information at least to get the cpu information, clock speed, cores unlocked, fan speed etc. using java because its the only complied language I know well after C.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect CPU Speed/Memory/Internet Speed using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297870/detect-cpu-speed-memory-internet-speed-using-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No and Yes.

Since Java is designed as an abstraction over multiple hardware configurations it is not possible by default.

On the other hand you can access it if you are using JNI or JNA to access a native library that can access that kind of information.

But if you know C well then *Don’t cross the stream to get water*, just use C then.