# In Java, how to get disk write and read bytes per seconds, network tx bytes and rx bytes per seconds?

Tags: java, metrics

I want to use pure java to get the stats of disk and network.
Especially:
In Java, how to get disk write and read bytes per seconds, network tx bytes and rx bytes per seconds?

Is that possible?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)???

Comment: I use java call sar command, but some system does not have it

Comment: And I found org.hyperic.sigar, but It only provides the total bytes, how to get bytes/sec? total bytes/ uptime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `proc` file system and `sysfs` give access to statistics like this.

You can read the network tx and rx from `/proc/net/dev` for example.

Disk statistics can be found in [`/proc/diskstats`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/procfs-diskstats).

Comment: I read /proc/net/dev, there are total received bytes and total transmit bytes, but how to get the bytes/secs? total received bytes / uptime?

Comment: That gives you the average speed bytes/sec for the entire uptime, which is probably not interesting. If you want to know what the transmission speed is "now" it's either 0 or the speed of the interface, which is also not very interesting. Maybe you could read the file every N seconds, compute the difference and divide by N, giving you the average speed over the N-second period.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking something similar to the following: [Detect CPU Speed/Memory/Internet Speed using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297870/detect-cpu-speed-memory-internet-speed-using-java).

You may also have some success using the `java.lang.management` package. Some boilerplate is described [here](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/03/java_tip_how_get_cpu_and_user_time_benchmarking).